# OpenCV read video file give different result in different VS project

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a simple script to read mp4 file like this.

```cpp
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::VideoCapture file("test.mp4");
    cv::Mat frame;
    while (true)
    {
            file.read(frame);
            cv::imshow("Preview", frame);
            cv::waitKey(42); 
    }
    file.release();
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine. But when I integrate this script into another project I'm working on. The the image frame shows in wrong aspect ratio.

Correct (Side by Side):

[image]

Wrong (Only show one side and aspect ratio is wrong):

[image]

I'm running on Windows VS2019. I have remove all other script in my exists project, just leave the above. The only different I can think of is the includes and linker setting. I use `ceres, glog, d3d11, realsense2, VTK, pcl, eigen3, OpenXR` in the project. Does any of that effects what OpenCV behave? Or what might be the problem?

- I've already try setting the frame width and height for VideoCapture and it's not working.
- I've test both OpenCV 4.1 and 4.6.
- When accessing frame.cols, frame.rows, I got the correcy resolution.

### UPDATE

The metadata of the file I'm trying to read is as below. This is a side by side 3D video. It also can display correctly in player such as VLC.

```
mediainfo test.mp4 
General
Complete name                            : test.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 181 MiB
Duration                                 : 31 s 339 ms
Overall bit rate                         : 48.4 Mb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.20.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L5.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 1 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 1 frame
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=30
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 31 s 317 ms
Bit rate                                 : 48.0 Mb/s
Width                                    : 3 840 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Original display aspect ratio            : 3.556
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 60.000 FPS
Minimum frame rate                       : 59.920 FPS
Maximum frame rate                       : 60.080 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.193
Stream size                              : 179 MiB (99%)
Title                                    : SStar Video
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 31 s 339 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 140 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 534 KiB (0%)
Title                                    : SStar Audio
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
```

Comment: what is the output of `std::cout<<frame.cols<<"  "<<frame.rows<<std::endl;` during run time ?

Comment: It's 3840  1080. I think that's correct.

Comment: there are two properties I noticed: Display aspect ratio and Original display aspect ratio. It can be related with them ?

Comment: That's a good point. I will look into it!